# PHP check if string is properly formatted

Tags: php, string, formatting

I have a PHP application which should require a special activation key for unlocking.
So I want to create scripts which will check if `$user_input` is properly formatted.

An activation key will be like this: 
`1E63-DE12-22F3-1FEB-8E1D-D31F`

Numbers and letters **spacing may vary.**
So activation key may be also like this or different:
`1EE3-1E1C-R21D-1FD7-111D-D3Q5`

1. Colons are separated with -
2. Every colon contains 4 characters which are a mix of letters and numbers

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I would use regex for this, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428343/regex-for-product-key

Comment: Why do you need to check if the code if well formatted, since if they mismatch something, the format or the code, it won't work. However, I would suggest, if you want the user to type in this format, put 6 text boxes with 4 maxlength, then concatenate with `-` each when you recieve the input

Comment: This is just for format checking, after that input will go to further checking. Anyway, your suggestion/idea is very good so I may use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use a regular expression for that. I've tested this regex here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

```
<?php

$key   = '1E63-DE12-22F3-1FEB-8E1D-D31F';
$regex = '^[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}$';

if (preg_match($regex, $key)) {
    echo 'Passed';
} else {
    echo 'Wrong key';
}
```

Comment: This works well after modification. Without modification it throws error "Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found" so I modified it to this

$regex = '/^[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}$/';


Thanks, your script does exactly what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match keys like the one you posted, and will also work if lowercase letters are included:

```
^([A-z0-9]){4}-([A-z0-9]){4}-([A-z0-9]){4}-([A-z0-9]){4}-([A-z0-9]){4}-([A-z0-9]){4}$
```

If you want only uppercase letters, change all the "z" in that regex for "Z"